# How to set css designs using loop in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83QGg.png)

->once look at my reference image

->In that image, I have taken one  for loop (for creating box design) and made that design above

->But I want to change the background colour and border colour for all the boxes using one HTML class name (like shown in the image)

->Border colour and the background colour should be different for every box.

-> And look at the second box in the image (loans) in that we can see crop loan admin but in other boxes, only members are there how to put condition for this?

->And in all the boxes arrow icon is there in the 1st row only how to put condition for this?

->How to do that? check my code I have used separate div for all the boxes I need to iterate using loop and bind names, border colour, and background colour for all boxes.

### Html

```
<mat-card class="mat mr-4 ml-5 p-3" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>


    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlex fxLayoutGap="20px">


      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">

      <!-- all-items  -->

      <div fxFlex="calc(33.3% - 20px)" class="m-1 pt-3">

        <div fxLayout class="cart-styling">

          <div class="overview-cart">

            <div class="ml-5 mt-4 heading-text">{{item?.title}}</div>

          </div>

          <img class="pr-5 mt-4" style="width: 90px;" alt="customer_icon" src="assets/icons/firsticon.png">

        </div>

        <div class="content pl-3">

          <div>

            <h6 fxLayoutAlign="space-between none" class="pb-1 pt-2 main-line border-bottom"> Members <mat-icon class="arrow-icon">arrow_right_alt</mat-icon> <span class="mr-4 value-color">1000</span></h6>

            <h6 fxLayoutAlign="space-between none" class="pb-1 line border-bottom"> Non-Members <span class="mr-4 value-color">200</span></h6>

            <h6 fxLayoutAlign="space-between none" class="pb-1 line border-bottom"> Traders <span class="mr-4 value-color">250</span></h6>

            <h6 fxLayoutAlign="space-between none" class="pb-1 line border-bottom"> Employee <span class="mr-4 value-color">40</span></h6>

            <h6 fxLayoutAlign="space-between none" class="pb-1 line border-bottom">-</h6>

            <h6>-</h6>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- /all-items  -->

    </ng-container>

    </div>

  </mat-card>
```

### CSS

```
.overview-cart {

  position: relative;

  width: calc(100% - 80px);

  background-color: #5f7dff;

  overflow: hidden;


  &:after {

    content: "";

    position: absolute;

    right: -175px;

    top: 0;

    border-width: 153px;

    border-style: solid;

    border-color: transparent;

    border-top-color: #fff;

    z-index: 99;

    transform: rotate(19deg);

  }

}


.cart-styling {

  width: 100%;

  justify-content: center;

  height: 30%;

  border: 1px solid #5f7dff;

}


.heading-text {

  font-size: 18px;

  font-weight: normal;

  color: #fff;

}


img {

  width: 90px;

  height: min-content;

}


.mat {

  height: auto;

}


.line {

  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;

  font-size: 14px;

}


.main-line {

  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;

  font-size: 14px;

  color: #0b4983;

}


.arrow-icon {

  line-height: 0.8;

  color: #0b4983;

  margin-right: 75%;

}


.value-color {

  color: #065a3d;

}


.content {

  background-color: #f7f7f9;

}
```

## Ts file

```
items: any[]= [

    {

      id : 0,

      title: 'Customer',

      submodules: {

        members: 1000,

        non_members: 200,

        traders: 250,

        employees: 40

      }

    },

    {

      id: 1,

      title: 'Loans',

      submodules: {

        Crop_loan_admin: 1000,

        non_members: 200,

        traders: 250,

        employees: 40

      }

    },

    {

      id: 2,

      title: 'Insurance',

      submodules: {

        members: 1000,

        non_members: 200,

        traders: 250,

        employees: 40

      }

    },

  // ]

  // lists: any[]=[


    {

      id: 3,

      title: 'Inventory',

      submodules: {

        members: 1000,

        non_members: 200,

        traders: 250,

        employees: 40

      }

    },

    {

      id: 4,

      title: 'Accounts',

      submodules: {

        members: 1000,

        non_members: 200,

        traders: 250,

        employees: 40

      }

    },

    {

      id: 5,

      title: 'Masters',

      submodules: {

        members: 1000,

        non_members: 200,

        traders: 250,

        employees: 40

      }

    },

  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

store your colors as a property to each `item`

```js
{

      id : 0,

      title: 'Customer',
      
      theme : "red", // for example 

      submodules: {

        members: 1000,

        non_members: 200,

        traders: 250,

        employees: 40

      }

    },
```

then use `ngStyl` in html file (check for the right div to place ngStyle

```
...

 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">

      <!-- all-items  -->

      <div fxFlex="calc(33.3% - 20px)" class="m-1 pt-3" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.theme, 'border-color': item.theme}">

        <div fxLayout class="cart-styling">

          <div class="overview-cart">

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with one `css` class. but you can do this:

adding `theme` color to you object:

```
items: any[]= [
  {
    id: 0,
    theme: '#ff0000',
    title: 'Customer',
    submodules: {
      members: 1000,
      non_members: 200,
      traders: 250,
      employees: 40
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    theme: '#00ff00',
    title: 'Loans',
    submodules: {
      Crop_loan_admin: 1000,
      non_members: 200,
      traders: 250,
      employees: 40
    }
  },
];
```

bind it to the HTML:

```
<mat-card class="mat mr-4 ml-5 p-3" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlex fxLayoutGap="20px">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">

      <div [style]="'background-color: ' + item.theme + '; border: 1px solid ' + item.theme + ';'" fxFlex="calc(33.3% - 20px)" class="m-1 pt-3">
      </div>

    </ng-container>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
```

this will apply specified theme to each card.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f1ipbh) example.

Comment: not working how css will work in TS file?

Comment: not css, you just store your color hex as a string and pass it to the dynamic style in html. @RevanthReddy

Comment: I provided this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f1ipbh take a look @RevanthReddy

Comment: but it is not working in my application shall we connect through meet my email is revredddy@gmail.com

Comment: Most troubled answer I ever gave :-D. Push the project in github and give me access mahdizarei0614@gmail.com

Comment: Or call me on skype live:mahdizarei0614